# Getting "Connection is Reset" in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I'm getting "Connection is Reset" on Magento admin panel, specifically on *System -> Sales -> Payment Methods* menu and I'm not sure how to trace the error. All other admin pages works perfectly fine. If I enable HTTPS, it sends "Secure Connection Failed". The problem lies specifically on this page.

How could I debug/trace find the cause of the problem? I'm using Magento version 1.13.0.2.

Comment: Why negative voting? what's wrong with the question.

Comment: Which magento version are you using?

Comment: @DeepKakkar Magento ver. 1.13.0.2

Comment: Could be your server timeout is too short.

Comment: Improved title, formatting and problem description.